# how to read this xml properties using xmltextreader

Tags: .net, xml

i have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<properties>
  <entry key="dbname">financedb</entry>
  <entry key="username">admin</entry>
  <entry key="password">root</entry>
</properties>
```

I need to have function in which i want to read all three key values and read into string using XMLTextreader ..ive tried this but i am clueless now what to do.

```
[WebMethod]
       public getConStrings()
        {         
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("/_layouts/SPCustomWS/zahid.xml");

             XmlNodeType type;
             while (reader.Read())
             {
               type = reader.NodeType;
               if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                 if (reader.Name == "dbname")
                      return reader.Value;
                }
             }
          }
```

actually i want something like the following using xml which i did with web.config

```
string ODataSource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OracleDataSource"].ToString();
string OUserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OracleUserID"].ToString();
string OPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OraclePassword"].ToString();
```

Comment: Any reason you want to use XmlTextReader in particular? It's likely to be *much* simpler with LINQ to XML.

Comment: well its because i dont know LINQ :) would appreciate if i can learn LINQ way of doing it. But i need to pick the xml from the path i specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd *definitely* use LINQ to XML for this:

```
private static string GetSetting(XDocument doc, string key)
{
    return doc.Root
              .Elements("entry")
              .Single(x => (string) x.Attribute("key") == key)
              .Value;
}

...
var document = XDocument.Load("/_layouts/SPCustomWS/zahid.xml");
var dataSource = GetSetting(document, "dbname");
var userName = GetSetting(document, "username");
var password = GetSetting(document, "password");
```

Note that `Single` will throw an exception if it can't find the key you're asking for. Usually this is appropriate - you wouldn't want to keep going without a password, for example. An alternative is to use `SingleOrDefault` and just cast the return value to `string` instead of using the `Value` property:

```
private static string GetSetting(XDocument doc, string key)
{
    return (string) doc.Root
                       .Elements("entry")
                       .SingleOrDefault(x => (string) x.Attribute("key") == key);
}
```

This will now return `null` if it can't find the setting you're looking for. It will still throw an exception if there's more than one entry with the same key though - which would indicate a broken configuration file.

Comment: Jon..awesome..you taught me something really nice..i didnt know that with few lines of code it is possible :)

Comment: wait a sec...jon i am getting following error...System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at SPCustomWS.OraSPDataXchange.GetSetting(XDocument doc, String key)
   at SPCustomWS.OraSPDataXchange.getConStrings()

Comment: @user342944: That suggests you haven't got an entry with the key you're looking for. Check your XML and the key you're providing.

Comment: ive fixed it but the result is in this format when i read one key..it shud be returned as a strign only "Vision Server" no xml brackets.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/">Vision Server</string>

Comment: @user342944: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean - but the sample you gave didn't have any namespaces in. It sounds like your actual file is very different to the one you showed.

Comment: accept my sincere apology jon..i got confused..result was from webservice test..your code was fantastic..it worked like a charm :)